# Finding Specific Data from Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coding in C#. I want to search for a name. And I want to display the details of that person from the database I am connected to. But all I am getting is

> Error " USE OF Unassigned Local Variable.

I tried to initialize the variable too. It executes but shows no output.

Here's my code...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=MITHILESH-PC\\SERVER101;Initial Catalog=People;Integrated Security=True");

        String find = " ";
        TextBox1.Text = find;

        String QueryString = "Select * from Members Where NAME='{find}' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString,cn);

        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Your `dr` has rows? Your `cmd` returns any data in your database manager? Also use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: try `String.format("Select * from Members Where NAME='{%s}' ", find);` instead of `"Select * from Members Where NAME='{find}' ";`

Answer (score 3):

```
String QueryString = "Select * from Members Where NAME=@Name ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString,cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
```

Add the value as parameter of SqlCommand, this is the correct way. In this case you will prevent sql injection attacks too.

Also in the begging of your code:

```
String find = " ";
TextBox1.Text = find;
```

Here you are making the Text of your checkbox equals to " ". If you want to store the `textBox` value in the variable find, you should write it like this: `string find = TextBox1.Text;`